# Docker containers no longer allow web access

Tags: apache, docker

I have a very strange issue on my local development environment. I have a couple of Docker containers that run a couple of different environments, but both fronted with Apache. Both are connected to the same bridge network and one has port 80 exposed and the other port 8010. When the containers are running I can connect using telnet as follows:

```
telnet localhost 80
```

or

```
telnet localhost 8010
```

However, from the browser, nothing happens and in the end, it just times out. In the logs on the Docker contains there is nothing to show an inbound connection.

From the Docker containers shell, I can access the HTTP server using curl without issue.

I tried deleting the bridge network and adding it again but that didn't help.

I've tried turning the macOS firewall off but that doesn't help.

If I stop the docker containers and then try the above telnet command it errors with "Connection refused" as would be expected, so the telnet command is definitely connecting to the docker container.

Also, this setup has been working fine for sometime until today.

I'm lost as to what to try next and have found nothing similar Googling.

Any ideas of how to resolve this would be gratefully received.

Answer (score 1):

To resolve this I did:

```
docker-compose rm -f
docker images --no-trunc --format '{{.ID}}' | xargs docker rmi
```

and then rebuilt the images / containers.

Be careful with the above as they are destructive commands.